# Function to get thumbnail img source

Tags: functions, images, thumbnails

I have this function call that displays an entire img tag with the correct url for that post.. the thumbnail img...

```
?php the_post_thumbnail('blog-page'); ?>
```

What I need is just the source address for that img.

How can I get that source dynamically?

---

Here is a little more explanation of what it is exaclty that I'm doing...

This is the code that displays the thumbnail for a page in my wordpress:

```
<div class="entry-thumbnail">
<a rel="lightbox" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('blog-page'); ?></a>
</div>
```

I need that a tag's href to use the img's source instead of linking to the blog post it's self to get lightbox to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
```

all together:

```
    <div class="entry-thumbnail">
       <a rel="lightbox" href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ); ?></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: the href returns blank with this.

Comment: are you using it in the loop? it works just fine for me.

Comment: I'm sure it's in the loop, otherwise the rest of the content wouldn't show, right?

Comment: G.M. pointed out a error below, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you use `the_post_thumbnail('blog-page')` where 'blog-page' is a custom image size previous registered with [add_image_size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size). So, if you want control thumbnail size, try this:

```
<?php
global $post;
$imageid = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
$image_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $imageid, 'blog-page' );
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $imageid );
/*
if you want to control image size also for lightbox (useful for very big images) use instead:
$image_large = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $imageid, 'large' );
$image_url = $image_large[0];
*/
?>

<div class="entry-thumbnail">
   <a rel="lightbox" href="<?php echo $image_url; ?>">
       <img src="<?php echo $image_thumb[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: All I want is the source address for the thumbnail. I'd think that Ron's code should work, since I can see how I'd construct the same code with what you've written here. Thanks for the extra advice though, I can see this being useful later on.

Comment: wp_get_attachment_url return the url of the _full_ image, not of the thumbnail. if you want the url of the thumbnail you have to use wp_get_attachment_image_src.

Comment: Ron's code probably don't work because `echo` is missing inside `href` attribute, before `wp_get_attachment_url`

Comment: good catch. I had fixed that on my local host and fergot to update the answer